# Are Qui-Gon And Obi-Wan from the same planet?

Tags: star-wars

I just noticed how similar there names are in formatting I mean they both have a Hyphenated first name and a separate last name and their accents are similar. So do they share a common home world?

Comment: I'm sorry to see this get downvoted; I think it's quite a valid question that you raise.  You have my +1!

Comment: And my axe!  ...Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No

According to [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Qui-Gon_Jinn) (referencing the book *[Ultimate Star Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Star_Wars)*), in canon Qui-Gonn Jinn's home planet is 
[Coruscant](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Coruscant), but Obi-Wan Kenobi's home planet is [Stewjon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Stewjon#cite_note-Obi-Wan_Kenobi-0) ([Source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Obi-Wan_Kenobi), referencing [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20140620104833/http://starwars.com/explore/encyclopedia/characters/obiwankenobi/)).  Apparently at a convention, Lucas joked that this was Obi-Wan's homeworld, so if Lucas said it is, I think we can accept that!

Comment: Would this be canon as of the Disney takeover or not? (Actually curious)

Comment: *Ultimate Star Wars* was published this year with reference to Force Awakens => probably canon

Comment: Regarding the other site, as far as I'm concerned, if Lucas said that is is homeworld, then it is

Comment: I remember reading in one of the books (canon because this was recently and that's all I've been reading) that Obi-Wan spoke with a "Coruscanti accent." Presumably because he was essentially raised there and picked it up from Qui-Gon.